# Finding total number of divisors which divide 2 given numbers

Tags: number-theory, factoring

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Number of common divisors between two given numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/8611/number-of-common-divisors-between-two-given-numbers)

I need to find the total number of divisors which divide both the numbers lets say N and M.
Actually I tried to think about it  a lot and searched at a lot of places for a possible answer. All I could think of was finding the prime factors and generating the actual divisors from the factors ?
However this would take a lot of computation,therefore I need a much faster method performing  much fewer operations?
Is there any well known algorithm or formula for this problem or any derivable formula?
I think the answer should be the number of divisors of the gcd of the 2 numbers.

Answer (score 4):

It is the number of divisors of the greatest common divisor (GCD) of N and M.  You can find the GCD by the [Euclidean algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm), which does not require factoring.  This is generally a smaller number than N or M, but then you need to factor it.  You don't need to generate all the divisors, you can use the [divisor function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_of_divisors) as the product of one more than the power of each prime dividing the GCD.

Comment: Do you mean "...the product of one more tha*n* the power of each prime..."?

Comment: @Code-Guru:  Yes, fixed

Answer (score -2):

let x = gcd(n,m) (greatest common devisor)
and then  x - oiler(x)
how to find the gcd u can read here - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor

how to calculate oiler function u can find here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function

(oiler fuction give you all the number strangers to your number)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. And learn how to spell the man's name: it's **Euler**.